# Can I use https for local development?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, same-origin-policy

I'm attempting a slight variation of the Google+ web sign-in server side flow as described on the [Google Developer's website](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow).

Google's gapi code is giving this error message:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://my-development-system.dev" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Am I right in saying that my local development system cannot be set up to use the https protocol?

Comment: The error says you are *not* using HTTPS. Do you mean that you don't want to pay for a trusted certificate? Did you find issues with self-signed certs?

Comment: I use it with apache but have to generate my own certificates

Comment: But reading the error tells me you are not using https at all.
generare your certs, configure apache to use ssl and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong in saying that

> my local development system cannot be set up to use the https protocol

It can! Simply by using self certification SSL.

Comment: This should not be the selected answer. The selected answer should go to @SilverlightFox. They have provided a good explanation of the theory behind how it works and also answered the question (3 days earlier).

Answer (score 1):

This is not only to do with a differing protocol (HTTP on your site vs HTTPS on `accounts.google.com`), it is also because the domain does not match (and port for that matter), a restriction imposed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

This policy stops `www.evil.com` from loading a site such as `www.bank.com` inside a frameset (or popup window if framing is disabled) and then accessing the DOM. If the DOM could be accessed, this would be a massive security risk as any website could read your private data on another site.

It is possible to allow access by implementing a [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) policy and outputting server side headers to allow other specified domains to read content, however this would be on Google's side in your case. So unless `https://accounts.google.com` implements a [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) policy, you will not be able to make a client-side variation of the server side flow. Another barrier is that even if CORS was implemented it does not allow access to the DOM. However, you'd be able to retrieve content from another domain, protocol or port via AJAX calls. The target site would also have to output the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header in order for authentication credentials (i.e. cookies in this case) to be sent with the request and the response read by your domain.

> Can I use https for local development?

To answer your original question, the answer is yes. This can be a self-signed certificate for most purposes and it will not affect this particular error message in your browser (as you, as the browser user has chosen to accept and trust the certificate).